# React The function called in onSubmit in a form is not run

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a form in react that should take what the user typed into the input field and then when submitted, it should direct the user to a new page.
For example: if the user typed `Mike`, it should redirect the user to `/Mike`
but when I click submit all that happens is that the input is added to the url as a parameter like `localhost:3000/?query=Mike`
Regarding malicious input I will probably deal with that when I fix this issue.

My code is as follows

```js
function search({ history }) {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState([]);
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    history.push(`/${query}`);
  };
  const handleChange = (text) => (e) => {
    setQuery(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => e.handleSubmit()}
        className=""
      >
        <div className="">
          <span className="">
            <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
          </span>
          <input
            onChange={handleChange("query")}
            type="text"
            name="query"
            
            className=""
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately it looks like as though the function specified in the `onSubmit` is never called I have tried this by using console.log. What it does is reload the page and add `?query=<INPUT>` to the URL
How can I fix this issue so that it redirects to the new page

Comment: Try location.href and pass the value of the input

Answer (score 2):

Inside `<form>`, you're doing `onSubmit={(e) => e.handleSubmit()}`. You're calling the `handleSubmit()` of the event object, not your own `handleSubmit` function. Instead, try this:

```js
function search({ history }) {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState([]);
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        history.push(`/${query}`);
        e.handleSubmit(); // if you still want to actually submit
    };
    const handleChange = (text) => (e) => {
        setQuery(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <form
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                className=""
            >
                <div className="">
                    <span className="">
                        <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input
                        onChange={handleChange("query")}
                        type="text"
                        name="query"

                        className=""
                    />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work and still does exactly the same thing it adds `?query=MYINPUT` to the url

Comment: Then replace `e.handleSubmit()` with `e.preventDefault(); return false;` to cancel the "native" form submission.